# Unable to execute different set of tasks on Ansible Tower , one tasks should execute on linux hosts and other set of task should execute on localhost

Tags: ansible, localhost, ansible-tower

Error: sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?\n

I have already tried using connection: local and delegate_to: localhost
Can anybody tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: Are you trying to `delegate_to: localhost` with `become: true` while running you playbook on awx/tower ?

Comment: Yes , I fixed it using blocks with privileges escalation in windows based tasks and used only delegate_to: localhost for ansible server tasks.